# Why does my daemon mysteriously close by itself?

Tags: macos, daemon

I've created a small daemon which allows me to control my external display's brightness via DDC. The thing is, after it's been running for ~30 mins or so, it inexplicably closes.

My main.swift is very straightforward:

```swift
import Foundation

let application = NSApplication.shared
let applicationDelegate = AppDelegate()

application.delegate = applicationDelegate
application.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
application.run()
```

The strange thing is, it seems to exit with exit code 0, and when in the debugger Xcode says it ended normally. Yet if I print something after `application.run()` or add a breakpoint there, it never seems to fire.

I've tried adding various symbolic breakpoints to `exit`, but it never manages to catch where it's happening, and I've got no calls to `exit` in the codebase anyway.

Why might my application be closing by itself? What can I do to work out the cause?

Comment: You call it a *"daemon"*. Are you starting it with `launchctl`? If not, then how, please?

Comment: Either by Finder, launchctl, Xcode or Terminal — it always ends the same way.